# How to send messages between users

Tags: support

Is there a feature for member-to-member messaging outside of the "chat" area? I would like to ask questions of clarification to an individual user, but I can't remember where I saw the comment that I want to clarify to respond directly to it.

Comment: If you have enough rep, you can create a new chat room.

Comment: But I just want to send a single message. I don't need all that pomp and circumstance and responsibility of hosting a chat room.

Comment: Well, that's what comments are made for. Can you retrace where the original comment was?

Comment: So far, no. It was something @Barrie England said about others, other's, and others'. Specifically, about the omission of the apostrophe for that word altogether.

Comment: Tylerharms — for your particular problem, there is the comments tab of the [activity page](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/12952/barrie-england?tab=activity) on the user profile. Search for "others"

Comment: [This one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92007/each-others-presence-vs-each-others-presence/92012#comment184947_92012)? That is five clicks from here. "Main" → "Users" → "Barrie England" → "Activity" → "Comments". Then use Ctrl+F or what have you to search. Really straightforward. **Edit:** jinx @Matt.

Comment: Okay, that works. Thank you. For the record, was there any implied sarcasm in "really straightforward"? I would hope a little.

Comment: Ah, no; no sarcasm on my part. Looking for a user's recent activity on that user's page under "activity" is indeed the very definition of "straightforward" in my book. This, in turn, is not to imply that you are expected to be aware of that tab — or of user pages, for that matter. Figuring such stuff out is one of the reasons why Meta exists in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Private messaging is not available on the Stack Exchange network. To contact a particular user, you can (since you have the prerequisite reputation amount) do either of the following:

1. Find the user in a chat room and talk to them there. To find out if a user is in a chat room, [search for them](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users).
2. [Create](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) a chat room and then, using the same method as above to find the user, invite them to your room.

Your particular problem can be solved, as RegDwight points out, by using the comments sub-tab of the user activity tab, on the [user's page](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/12952/barrie-england?tab=activity). Once there, use your browser's text search facility to find the text you are looking for.

Comment: Don't high rep (10K+?) users have a way to message each other somehow?

Comment: @Luke nope. Mods have special rooms and the ability to ping people in chat who haven't been there before. 10kers are as limited as the rest.

Comment: @MattЭллен Really? You mean you have never sent a message via a comment, then deleted it? People seem to do that to me all the time. It still shows up in the inbox, but nowhere else that non-mods can see.

Comment: @tchrist — I have never done that. I didn't know that would happen.